# Evaluating $\lim _{h\to 0^+}f(x-y)g(x/h)/h^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be locally integrable in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bounded (Lebesgue) measurable function that vanishes outside of a compact set. I am trying to show that $\lim_{h\to 0^+}\int f(x-y)\cdot g(x/h)/h^n=f(x)\int g(y)dy$ for almost every $x$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$, but I don't know how to deal with the function $f$.

I'm not sure if covolution is needed here, but it looks like it is being used on the left hand side. I'm not sure how that would help. The left side looks like $g(x)$ according to Lebesgue's differentiation theorem, but I don't know how to deal with the $f(x-y)$ factor. Can I get some direction here?

Comment: there seems to be a typo. see my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idea is $$\int \frac{f(y - x)g(x/h)}{h^n} dx  = 
\int f(y - hu ) g(u) du \to  \int f(y ) g(u) du  = f(y)\int g(u)du
$$
using a change of variable and the dominated convergence theorem.